# MaterializeCSS Timepicker can't set initial time?

Tags: javascript, html, materialize, timepicker

I have ran into a problem using MaterializeCSS Timepicker component.

It seems that it's not possible to set initial value that actually **SHOWS** in the component. The only behavior I can get is that time is chosen when I open the modal and once I click OK, then it actually shows that time in the component.

This is how the component looks like when I load the page:
[image: Initial look]

And this is how it looks like when I open that timepicker, and just click OK:
[image: Wanted look]

Is there a way to make this component show this initial value without having to click OK?

NOTE: Setting time property does nothing visually, nor does defaultTime option during initialization.

Comment: You might be able to set the components value using jQuery's `$(elem).val(yourTime)` or with plain javascript.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick.
Wanted to achieve this through the actual component, but hey, it has the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I achieved what I think you're asking:

```
const defaultTime = '14:26';
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
const timeInstance = M.Timepicker.init(myInput, {
    defaultTime: defaultTime
});

// forces materialize time picker to display default time in input
timeInstance._updateTimeFromInput();
timeInstance.done();
```

Based on a similar question asked [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5575)